# how to get data from multiple related tables and pass it to the view mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, lambda, entity-framework-5

i have three table in my data base category and Subcategory and product:

category has many Subcategory
Subcategory has many product

so i'm trying to join this three table to get the data for each product and display it in a view like that:

```
 public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var memberId = WebSecurity.CurrentUserId;

        var productsCompany = db.Products
        .Join(db.SubCategorys, p => p.SubCategoryID, subcat => subcat.SubCategoryID,
                     (p, subcat) => new { p = p, subcat = subcat })
        .Join(db.Categorys, temp0 => temp0.subcat.CategoryID, cat => cat.CategoryID,
                     (temp0, cat) => new { temp0 = temp0, cat = cat })
        .Join(db.Sizes, temp1 => temp1.temp0.p.SizeID, s => s.SizeID,
                     (temp1, s) => new { temp1 = temp1, s = s })
        .Join(db.Colors, temp2 => temp2.temp1.temp0.p.ColorID, c => c.ColorID,
                     (temp2, c) => new { temp2 = temp2, c = c })
        .Join(db.Stores, temp3 => temp3.temp2.temp1.temp0.p.StoreID, st => st.StoreID,
                     (temp3, st) => new { temp3 = temp3, st = st })
        .Join(db.Companyies, temp4 => temp4.st.CompanyID, camp => camp.CompanyID,
                     (temp4, camp) => new { temp4 = temp4, camp = camp })
        .Where(temp5 => (temp5.camp.UserID == memberId))
        .Select(temp5 => new
        {
            CategoryName = temp5.temp4.temp3.temp2.temp1.cat.CategoryName,
            SubCategoryName = temp5.temp4.temp3.temp2.temp1.temp0.subcat.SubCategoryName,
            ProductImageURL = temp5.temp4.temp3.temp2.temp1.temp0.p.ProductImageURL,
            ProductName = temp5.temp4.temp3.temp2.temp1.temp0.p.ProductName,
            Price = temp5.temp4.temp3.temp2.temp1.temp0.p.Price,
            SizeName = temp5.temp4.temp3.temp2.s.SizeName,
            ColorName = temp5.temp4.temp3.c.ColorName,
            Quantity = temp5.temp4.temp3.temp2.temp1.temp0.p.Quantity,
            Sales = temp5.temp4.temp3.temp2.temp1.temp0.p.Sales,
            Discount = temp5.temp4.temp3.temp2.temp1.temp0.p.Discount,
            StoreName = temp5.temp4.st.StoreName,
            CompanyName = temp5.camp.CompanyName
        }).ToList();

        return View(productsCompany);
    }
```

but in this way it take time to get the data so i' trying another way like that:

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var memberId = WebSecurity.CurrentUserId;

        var productsCompany = db.Products.Include(p => p.Color).Include(p => p.Size).Include(p => p.Store).Include(p => p.SubCategory); 

        return View(productsCompany.ToList());
    }
```

but i cant figure out how can i get the data from the threed table category in this way and this only for display the data in this index view any idea on how can i create a new product from this three tables and thanks for any help

Update my classes is:

Product class

```
public class Product
{
    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    public int ProductID { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Image URL")]
    //[DataType(DataType.Url)]
    public string ProductImageURL { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Product Name is required")]
    [DisplayName("Product Name")]
    [StringLength(40)]
    public string ProductName { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Price is required")]
    [DisplayName("Product Price")]
    [DataType(DataType.Currency)]
    [Range(1, 5000.00, ErrorMessage = "Price must be between 1 SP and 5000.00 SP")]
    public decimal Price { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Quantity is required")]
    [DisplayName("Product Quantity")]
    public int Quantity { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Sales Amount")]
    [Range(0, 100, ErrorMessage = "sale Prsent must be between 1 and 100")]
    public int Sales { get; set; }

    //Exclude
    public decimal Discount { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Color is required")]
    [DisplayName("Color")]
    public int ColorID { get; set; }
    public virtual Color Color { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Size is required")]
    [DisplayName("Size Type")]
    public int SizeID { get; set; }
    public virtual Size Size { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Store is required")]
    [DisplayName("Store")]
    public int StoreID { get; set; }
    public virtual Store Store { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Category Type is required")]
    [DisplayName("Sub Category Type")]
    public int SubCategoryID { get; set; }
    public virtual SubCategory SubCategory { get; set; }


}
```

Subcategory class:

```
 public class SubCategory
{

    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    public int SubCategoryID { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Category Type is required")]
    [DisplayName("Category Type")]
    [StringLength(40)]
    public string SubCategoryName { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Category is required")]
    [DisplayName("Category")]
    public int CategoryID { get; set; }
    public virtual Category Category { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Product> Products { get; set; }
}
```

Category class:

```
 public class Category
{

    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    public int CategoryID { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Category Name is required")]
    [DisplayName("Category Name")]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string CategoryName { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<SubCategory> SubCategorys { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> Assuming that your category, sub category and product table are relate with forign key

If you are using **Entity Framework** to access the data from database and **ProxyCreationEnabled** is set to true (by default it is true) in your dbContext class constructor, The product table will automatically retrieve the related category and subcategory data for the specific product.

### For example:

```
Product objProduct =  _datacontext.Product.where(p=> p.productId.equals(pid));
```

and your Product table is defined as below:

```
public class Product
{
    public int productId {get; set;}
    ...
    public virtual IEnumarable<Category> pCategories {get; set;} 
    public virtual IEnumarable<SubCategory> pSubCategories {get; set;}
}
```

so now your **objProduct** will automatically store the related Category and SubCategory in pCategories and pSubCategories respectively. you can access it directly, **No need to Join or Inclue the related tables explicitly.**

Now pass the object to the view as a Model

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    Product objProduct =  _datacontext.Product.SingleOrDefault(p=> p.productId.equals(pid));

    return View(objProduct);
}
```

and use the Model in the view as per requirement.

Comment: thank you for your answer but i'm trying to get all the products in the database withe the related subcategory and category for each product and like i mention in the question i have category has many Subcategory Subcategory has many product i will update the question to add my classes

Comment: Try to get `var productList =  _datacontext.Product.toList();`