# how read 2 table data having one to many relation form SQL in Entity Framework

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, linq-to-entities

i am new  in  ASP.NET  its  my first  application in ASP.NET MVC how to  get data of product and  category in Product Object
please check my controller.

Category Class

```
 public partial class Category
    {
        public Category()
        {
            Products = new HashSet<Product>();
        }
        public int categoryId { get; set; }

        [StringLength(50)]
        public string categoryTitle { get; set; }

        public int? categoryIndex { get; set; }           

        public virtual ICollection<Product> Products { get; set; }
    }
```

Product Class

```
public partial class Product
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public int categoryId { get; set; }

        [StringLength(50)]
        public string productTitle { get; set; }

        [UIHint("tinymce_jquery_full"),  AllowHtml ]
        public string productDescription { get; set; }

        [StringLength(1)]
        public string status { get; set; }

      public virtual Category Category { get; set; }
    }
```

Controller

```
public ActionResult Index()
        {
             DataContext db = new DataContext();
              // var products = db.Products.Where(a =>a.productImage !=   // here is some code for getting list of products with category details  ) 
              // want to save value in product so that i can read like this 

              // products.productTitle;
              // products.productDescription ;
              // products.Category.categoryId ;
              // products.Category.categoryTitle ;

            return View(products);
        }
```

its  easy to get all product data  in "var product" variable but i need  all producta with  category id and category name like this products.Category.categoryTitle ;

i am using  "code first from database" approach.

Comment: unable to understand your requriment.

Comment: What is the problem? Apparently you're doing it the right way...

Comment: in "var products" variable  i want to save  both product and category data.  so that i can read like  products.productTitle; products.Category.categoryId ;

Comment: how to save data in "public  virtual Category Category { get; set; }" in Product Class. its  easy to get all product but  how  get all product with  category name

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13047845/how-to-include-a-child-objects-child-object-in-entity-framework-5

Comment: Please refer [this stack overflow question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24583396/how-to-get-data-from-multiple-related-tables-and-pass-it-to-the-view-mvc/24583549#24583549)

Comment: Hiren Kagrana i see  link  there mention "The product table will automatically retrieve the related category and subcategory data for the specific product.No need to Join or Inclue the related tables explicitly." but in my case  only  product information get  product.Category = NULL display

Comment: You have to tell Entity Framework to load entities i.e. category linked with the product. And the way to do that is using Include explicitly. e.g. db.Products.Include(o => o.Category).Single(o => o.Id == id); See the link I shared in my earlier comment.

Comment: SBirthare see my error [link](http://greenwoodpaintingswfl.com/error.png)

Comment: I am using "code first from database" approach. That's why category not load. now i am using "Database First" now every thing working fine Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
public ActionResult Index()
        {
             DataContext db = new DataContext();
         var products =(from u in db.products
                         select u).ToList(); // this will return all products
            return View(products);
        }
```

I would create a context reference for my database shadow that is Entity and I have initiated it with new instance `DataContext db= new DataContext();`

Now from the source of entity designer where tables are shown in diagrams will appear in intellisense.

This is simple query -

```
 var products =(from u in db.products
                             select u).ToList();
```

**Note- **
Now I can access table `products`.

If you access two tables than this will help you..

```
var products =(from u in db.products
              join v on u.primarykeycolumn equals v.foreignkeycolumn
                                 select new{ u,v}).ToList();
```

Here `u.primarykeycolumn equals v.foreignkeycolumn` is condition that is connect both tables

Comment: You should provide some context for your answer and explain how it solves the OP's problem. Otherwise, there is a chance that it will be deleted, as it was automatically flagged as "low quality".

Comment: yes you  can Now access table products. but i want category with product table.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var graph = db.Products.Include("Category").toList();
```

I would suggest you read about Lazy Loading, Explicit Loading and Eager Loading.
http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/EntityFramework4.3/eager-loading-with-dbcontext.aspx